# Запуск кода С/C++ на Python

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, c

На данный момент про Python я знаю только то, что он существует.
Хотел задать такой вопрос: возможно ли в к программе написанной на Python - каким то образом "подключить" код написанный на С++, чтобы этот код С++ выполнялся во время работы кода Python ?

И, если да, то, как происходит скажем так "объединение" данный между С++ и Python - я имею ввиду следующее: предположим на С++ объявлен массив/вектор и в Python объявлен массив и возможно ли "обменяться" данными между этими массивами, ну то есть скопировать данные из одного в другой ?

Или же все намного сложнее, чем я нарисовал у себя в голове ?

Comment: Можно C++ код скомпилировать в exe или dll (в исполняемый файл или библиотеку), потом вызывать из Python. Условно, пишите на C++ код для библиотеки, в ней экспортируете функцию, например, с параметром-массивом, в Python эту библиотеку подключаете (например через ctypes), вызываете функцию с передачей массив.

Comment: Кроме стандартного модуля ctypes можно еще использовать библиотеки cffi и pybind11, см. статью https://habr.com/ru/post/468099/

Comment: Как  описал @insolor реализуется "интерфейс C", т.е. функции идут с модификатором `extern "C"`, либо компиляция dll в режиме C, а не C++. Есть достаточно удобная кроссплатформенная "обвязка" swig (https://www.swig.org), которая позволяет соорудить питон-интерфейс к функциям с интерфейсом С++, классам.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html